# Rails Fog storage : NameError: uninitialized constant Azure::Core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, fog, rails-activestorage

I previously an app with Fog Storage on Rails 5.0.

Now i'm creating a new rails app in Rails 5.2 with active storage and fog storage.

I want that rails app upload, attach and download some files and parse every night a Azur blob where other application store other file.

I choose to add fog storage to my new app to read the file create from other app.

I add this lines to the gemfile

```
gem "azure-storage", require: false
gem 'fog-azure-rm'
```

and I create a z_fog_cloud_storage.rb like that:

```
require 'fog/azurerm'

FogStorage = Fog::Storage::AzureRM.new(
  azure_storage_account_name:   CONFIG["access_key_id"],                                             # Name of an Azure Storage Account
  azure_storage_access_key:     CONFIG["secret_access_key"],     # Azure cloud environment. Default is AzureCloud.
  environment: '<AzureCloud>'
)

StorageBucket = FogStorage.directories.new key: CONFIG["bucket"]
```

I also add everything to get Active storage work.

Sadely I get this error when I'm trying to acces to the file

```
2.3.4 :003 > StorageBucket.files
NameError: uninitialized constant Azure::Core
```

I don't find any answer on google. Its should be a basic mistake or maybe active-storage is not compatible with Fog or fog is not compatible with rails 5.2

Thanks for your help

## SOLUTION

I simply have a wrong access_key_id in my setup file
.. sorry for distrub

Comment: I have never use Azure but i think you have to install azure gem https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby try it.

Comment: @ErickEduardoGarcia , thanks for your answer. but I didn't add the azure gem  in the previous application and it works, ....